# Why does the Hausdorff distance between $I=[0,1]$ and $B_n = \{0, \frac{1}{n}, \cdots, \frac{n-1}{n}, 1\}$ tend to zero?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, fractals

I have a proof of this; I understand the implications of all the steps, but I am struggling to understand why a particular step is true, namely the statement

> $B_n \subset I$  so we can say:$$\ \sup_{b \in B_n} \inf_{a \in I} d(a,b) = 0$$.

Why can we say this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Isn't the distance equal to $\frac{1}{2^n}$ (which of course decreases to $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$)?

Comment: Actually it's $\frac{1}{2n}$ which tends to 0, so you're on the right lines.

Comment: Well, this statement is just incorrect - the distance is certainly $1/(2n)$.

Comment: @MarkMcClure : Since $B_n \subset I$, the Hausdorff distance is $0$ for all $n$.  In fact, the Hausdorff distance from each point of $B_n$ to I$ is $0$.  What is it you think is going on?

Comment: @Joseph Could you please consider improving your question, as it is an interesting one for this site. Specifically, the Hausdorff distance between $I$ and $B_n$ is *not* zero, it is $1/(2n)$. In some texts, there is an intermediate definition yielding a non-symmetric notion of distance $d(A,B)$; the Hausdorff distance is then defined to be $\max(d(A,B),d(B,A))$. Is this what you mean? Or something else, like $d(I,B_n)\to 0$. It's hard to tell.

Comment: @MarkMcClure : If you are interested in the other half of the proof, regarding $\sup_{a \in I} \inf_{b \in B_n} d(a,b) = 1/2n$, why don't you post your own question?

Comment: @EricTowers Because I'm not confused. :)

Comment: @MarkMcClure : So far, you're the only person demanding an Answer to an unasked Question.  This indicates you're the only confused one here.

Comment: I agree with @MarkMcClure. I think just changing the title of the question could make everyone happy, because the Haussdorf distance is not equal to $0$. This being said, EricTowers did answer the OP's question, as he clarified the proof.

Comment: @Kuifje is correct, the question could be improved. Alternatively, Eric's answer could be improved to address what appears to me to be a point of confusion on the part of the OP.

Comment: @MarkMcClure's excessively opaque comments seem to indicate that he has a problem with the Questions title that he is unwilling to actually be explicit about.  Perhaps if he would *actually say* what he has a problem with, rather than being repeatedly, uselessly oblique and intentionally conflationary, he might get what he wants.

Comment: I've edited the title. Does anyone feel like getting on with some actual maths now? ;)

Comment: I am in agreement with @Eric Towers though.

Comment: @EricTowers I don't feel I've been opaque. I think there are two possible interpretations to this question and, if fact, I think your answer does not immediately address the intended question. I will post my own answer in an attempt to clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $b \in B_n$.  Then also $b \in [0,1]$, so $\inf_{a \in I} d(a,b) = d(b,b) = 0$.

Comment: Gotta downvote this as it ignores the obvious fact that the statement is incorrect.

Comment: @MarkMcClure : First, the statement is not the question, so your downvote conflates an externality.  Secondly, what do you think is the Hausdorff distance between a set and any of its subsets?

Comment: Well, for one thing, I think it's a metric. By your logic, $d(\{0\},[0,1])=d(\{1\},[0,1])=0$ so that, by the triangle inequality, $d(\{0\},\{1\})\leq d(\{0\},[0,1])+d(\{1\},[0,1])=0$.

Comment: @Mark McClure I think you know what the question is asking, please stop being so pedantic. Yes, for a given $n$, the Hausdorff distance is $\frac{1}{2n}$, but as $n$ tends to infinity, the distance tends to 0. I think everyone understood the question.

Comment: @Joseph I don't think that's how Eric read your question at all. :) There's a very important distinction here. Please consider improving your question, as I indicated in my recent comment to your question.

Comment: @MarkMcClure : I read his question as asking about one direction in his proof.  Why do you insist on conflating it with the other direction.  In fact, what is causing you to conflate everything with everything else?  Are you having a stroke?

Comment: @EricTowers Yes, that is exactly the direction that I guessed you were reading this. However, it was not clear to me from the original question that was the OP's intention. In fact, his recent comment that the distance tends to zero as $n\to\infty$ supports that view.

Comment: @Mark McClure if you have such an issue with the actual title of the question, please feel free to edit it yourself.

Comment: MarkMcClure always gives excellent answers to fractal related questions, he is not being pedantic, he is only trying to improve the way the question is asked, as it is a great one.

Answer (score 2):

Let us first clearly state the definition of the Hausdorff distance. For ease of reference, I will refer to the [definition on Wikepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) which says, given a metric $d$ on a metric space and compact sets $X$ and $Y$,

$$d_H(X,Y) = \max\left(\sup_{x\in X}\inf_{y\in Y}d(x,y),\sup_{y\in Y}\inf_{x\in X}d(y,x)\right).$$

In the question at hand, $d$ is simply the standard metric on $\mathbb R$: $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. We are asked to show why $d_H(I,B_n)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ where $I$ is the unit interval and
$$B_n = \{0,1/n,2/n,\ldots,(n-1)/n,1\}.$$
In fact, we'll show that $d_H(I,B_n)=1/(2n)$.

We first claim that
$$\sup_{y\in B_n}\inf_{x\in I}d(x,y) = 0.$$
This is a simple consequence of the fact that each $y\in B_n$ is also an element of $I$. Thus,
$$\inf_{x\in I}d(x,y) = 0 \text{ for all } y\in B_n.$$
Next, we claim that
$$\sup_{x\in I}\inf_{y\in B_n}d(x,y) = \frac{1}{2n}.$$
We can see this as follows: for every $n$, $i/n+1/(2n)$ is an element of $I$ whose distance from $B_n$ is $1/(2n)$. A look at a simple picture shows there are no points of $I$ that are farther away:

[image]

Of course, the actual Hausdorff distance is the larger of these two, namely $1/(2n)$ and $1/(2n)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ to answer the question as currently asked.