# Is the Hausdorff distance between $I=[0,1]$ and $B_n = \{0, \frac{1}{n}, \cdots, \frac{n-1}{n}, 1\}$ $0$ or $\frac{1}{2n}$?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, hausdorff-measure

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001170/why-is-the-hausdorff-distance-between-i-0-1-and-b-n-0-frac1n-cd), it is claimed that the  Hausdorff distance $d_H$ between $I=[0,1]$ and $B_n = \{0, \frac{1}{n}, \cdots, \frac{n-1}{n}, 1\}$ equals zero.

Is it not equal to $\frac{1}{2n}$ ?

For example, if $n=1$, $B_1=\{0,1\}$, and since $(B_1)_{\frac{1}{2}}=I$, I believe the Hausdorff distance equals
$$
d_H(I,B_1)=\inf\{\varepsilon\;|\; I \subseteq (B_1)_\varepsilon,B_1\subseteq I_{\varepsilon} \} = \frac{1}{2}
$$

With the same logic, we can show that 
$$
d_H(I,B_n)=\frac{1}{2n} \rightarrow0
$$

Is this correct?

**Note**: the notation $A_{\varepsilon}$ denotes the $\varepsilon$-thickening of the considered set $A$, that is, the set of points at a distance to any point of $A$ smaller than $\varepsilon\ge0$.

Comment: You are correct: the Hausdorff distance between $B_n$ and $I$ is $\frac1{2n}$. The Hausdorff distance between two sets is $0$ if and only if the sets have the same closure, so the Hausdorff distance between distinct closed sets is never $0$.