# The Hausdorff distance between sequences of sets

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, gromov-hausdorff-limit

Here is my problem. 
Consider 3 sequences of sets, for $n\rightarrow \infty$:

$$A_n=\{\frac{n-1}{n},\frac{n}{n+1}\}$$

$$B_n=(\frac{n-1}{n},\frac{n}{n+1})$$

$$C_n=[\frac{n-1}{n},\frac{n}{n+1}]$$

which sequence converges in the Hausdorff distance to $\{1\}$?

Given the definition, and in particular the part that defines convergence in terms of closures, to me it seems that only $B_n$ convergence to $\{1\}$.

But maybe I am confused with my intuition? Thanks for all hints!

Comment: Is $A_n$ a two-point set?

Comment: What formula for Hausdorff distance are you using?

Comment: Hausdorff distance is defined only for closed sets. Since $B_n$'s are open, the Hausdorff distance is not defined for them

Comment: In the Vietoris topology, $C_n \to \{1\}$ but not the $A_n$, the $B_n$ are not even closed, so they are not in the hyperspace. The Vietoris topology is the topology the Hausdorff distance induces (on compact metric spaces at least).

Comment: @MichaelBurr and what is the Hausdorff distance between $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ ? Is it zero? If yes, it cannot be a metric.

Comment: @ThePortakal Good point.

Comment: Thank you all for quick reactions! @UmbertoP. Yes each $A_n$ is a two-point set.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I meant this definition https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001282/is-the-hausdorff-distance-between-i-0-1-and-b-n-0-frac1n-cdots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that "every" point of $\{1\}$ is at distance $\le \frac1n$ from every point of $A_n$ and vice versa. Hence $d(A_n,\{1\})=\frac1n\to 0$.

The same works for $C_n$, so also $C_n\to\{1\}$.

This would also work for $B_n$ if we were to extend the notion of Hausdorff distance to non-compact sets in a reasonable way. However, you must be aware that this is a bad idea: the distance between $B_n$ and $C_n$ would then be zero, and we no longer have a metric.